# Unique device Id missing in MobileFirst Platform 7.1-based Windows Phone app

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

**Step 1**
When I submit answer in handle challenge of `WL.Client.createWLChallengeHandler` in the **very first** request, the headers section contains `wl_deviceNoProvisioningRealm` which also contains a device ID which is different from the device id received when using `WL.Device.getID`.

At the time of login, the server saves the device id and at the time of accessing the protected resources, it compares the device id with `oAuthSecurityContext.getDeviceIdentity().getId()`  in order to maintain unique login: one device - one user.

> {"AppRealm":{"parameters":{"reqURL":"/mobile/user/authentication","user.name":"tesla","user.password":"password","user.deviceId":"025bdc29-959c-4b0c-8a89-cf85b0790aaf"},"headers":{}},"wl_deviceNoProvisioningRealm":{"ID":{"token":"o2rp4qn6skhij80v2lk74bq2nu","app":{"id":"ollections","version":"1.0"},"device":{"id":"+obkd/fe9Py8y9/RVgVqT3oot2sl6FzVE1AKAAOOHww=","os":"8.10.14234.0","model":"RM-1019_1003","environment":"windowsphone8"},"custom":{}}}}

**Step 2**
When handling a scenario of a failure occurring due to wrong login credentials, if I submit the answer again in the **second** request, `wl_deviceNoProvisioningRealm` is not present so the device Id can't be received on server-side.

See below object:

> {"AppRealm":{"parameters":{"reqURL":"/mobile/user/authentication","user.name":"tesla","user.password":"password","user.deviceId":"025bdc29-959c-4b0c-8a89-cf85b0790aaf"},"headers":{}}

why am I getting different device IDs in Windows Phone only but same device ID in Android and iOS?

ID generated by IMF request auth header: 
`+obkd/fe9Py8y9/RVgVqT3oot2sl6FzVE1AKAAOOHww=`
ID generated by Wl.Device.getID :
`025bdc29-959c-4b0c-8a89-cf85b0790aaf`

Comment: Are you tracking device id at the server? Trying to understand what is the issue you are facing?

Comment: yes. while login , on server we fetched the device id and saved to db after fetching from request :String header = request.getHeader(AUTHORIZATION_HEADER);
   JSONObject headerJSON = JSONObject.parse(header);
   JSONObject deviceNoProvisioningJSON = (JSONObject) headerJSON.get("wl_deviceNoProvisioningRealm");
   if(deviceNoProvisioningJSON != null){
    JSONObject idJSON = (JSONObject) deviceNoProvisioningJSON.get("ID");
    JSONObject device = (JSONObject) idJSON.get("device");
    deviceId = (String) device.get("id");